# disable checkbox selection in Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

is it possible to disable checkbox selection by preserving some selected rows rendered with some constraints? 
I dont want to allow users to deselect rows which were selected while rendering.

I found `this.gridOptions.suppressCellSelection = true;` but this just hides the checkbox whereas i need to show the checkbox in disable mode.

Thanks.

Comment: never used this lib, but it looks like that you have to add some property to each row you want to disable, instead of looking for a grid-wide solution.

Comment: these checkbox are rendered but ag-grid implementation. so thought if there is an api then its easy.

Comment: For future reference, here is complete info on [disabling checkbox in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012540/7977581).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved it by adding `rowClassRules` in GridOptions

```
            rowClassRules: {
                'ag-row-selected' : function(params) {
                    return params.node.selected === true;
                },
            },
```

This will add css as below to disable checkbox click

```
.ag-row-selected{
        .ag-cell .ag-cell-wrapper .ag-selection-checkbox .ag-icon-checkbox-checked {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
```

RowClass rules are applied when grid is updated/refreshed or nodes are updated. I did it by updating specific nodes

```
           node.setSelected(true);
           // this is to trigger rowClass for selected/non-selected rows
           // to disable checkbox selection
           node.setData(node.data);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
 cellStyle: params => {
          return params.data.myStatus ? {'pointer-events': 'none', opacity: '0.4' }
            : '';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the builtin `agGroupCellRenderer` to render checkbox for multiple selection, you can turn off the node's `selectable` flag when deciding whether to render checkbox or not.

```
cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer",
cellRendererParams: {
    checkbox: function(params) {
        const node = params.node;
        const isGroupRow = node.level === 0; //only show the checkbox on group row.

        if(isGroupRow) {
            params.node.selectable = //your condition whether the rendered checkbox is selectable or not
        }

        return isGroupRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you save my time!
God bless you

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS workaround:

```
.ag-selection-checkbox.ag-hidden {
  display: inherit !important;
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

This will overwrite the display:none configuration in ag-hidden for the checkbox wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
columnDefination: [{ headerName: 'IsActive', field: '', editable: false, cellRenderer: params => { return `<input type='checkbox' disabled=true  ${params.data.IsActive ? 'checked' : ''} />`; } },],
```

Comment: please explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: I updated the code. I added inline checkbox in column defination and it worked in my project. You can ask me more detail, if I can't  explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the header of the ag-grid checkbox when filter data is found none then this might be helpful

```
   headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly:true
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works but when user clicks on Select All or Unselect All option from Header this gets changed automatically

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33483662)

Answer (score 0):

The feature to display Disabled Checkboxes is added to AG grid in version 28.1.0.
Changelog here https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=28.1.0 .
Here is the example from official docs https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#example-disabled-checkboxes
In addition a feature also allows to checkboxes as selected and disabled. e.g. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#example-force-enable-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing this:

- use `isRowSelectable={(node) => node.data?.columnName !== "something"}` in gridConfig to determine which row to set as not selectable
- set showDisabledCheckboxes: true in column defs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to select just the last level in a tree group, I achieve this using the following method:

```
autoGroupColumnDef = {
  
    checkboxSelection: function (params: Record<string, any>) {
      params.node.selectable = params.node.allLeafChildren.length == 1;
      return params.node.allLeafChildren.length == 1;
    },
   
  };
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/tree-data/

Answer (score -1):

One way is to add a cellRenderer function to the column for which the checkbox is need to be implemented.  You can enable or disable the checkbox by returning true or false from the cellRenderer function.

Comment: I am using ag-grid internal api to render checkbox not cellRenderer

Comment: cellRenderer requires you to return string, not boolean.